# Why we cannot combine sort the list and print the sorted list in one line

Tags: python, methods, printing

```
bakki =['a','b','B','A']    
print(bakki.sort())
```

The output of above code is None whereas if I write print and the mthod seperately like below

```
bakki =['a','b','B','A']    
bakki.sort()    
print(bakki)
```

The output of above code prints correctly as
['A', 'B', 'a', 'b']

Comment: Because the `sort `method returns `None`, as it sorts in-place. Use `sorted` instead.

Comment: No its not about sort() method. I am asking about print() . Why we cannot combine sort the list and print the sorted list in one line

Comment: `print` just prints whatever you pass to it. In the first case you are passing `None` which is the return value of the function `bakki.sort()`. In your second example you aren't printing the return value of the sort function, you are printing the variable `bakki`. `bakki` has been modified due to calling its sort method.

Answer (score 0):

'The sort() method doesn't return any value. Rather, it changes the original list.

If you want a function to return the sorted list rather than change the original list, use sorted().'

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

Comment: No its not about sort() method. I am asking about print() . Why we cannot combine sort the list and print the sorted list in one line

Comment: list.sort() will always return None. Printing list.sort() is totally different from print(list), as it will print the output of the sort method, which is None. If you want to sort and write the sorted list in one line, use print(sorted(bakki))

Comment: okay thanks Man Got it!